# Liveview not working in Alloy Projects (Working fine with Classic projects) in Appcelerator Studio

Tags: android, node.js, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I am trying to run my Alloy project with Liveview support. But it doesn't work and gives me the below error.

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.2.2
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
2016-05-30T06:19:24.631Z | TRACE  | set environment to {"registry":"https://software.appcelerator.com","security":"https://security.appcelerator.com","baseurl":"https://platform.appcelerator.com"}
2016-05-30T06:19:24.633Z | TRACE  | checking credentials for existing session
2016-05-30T06:19:24.925Z | TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
2016-05-30T06:19:24.931Z | TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
2016-05-30T06:19:26.722Z | TRACE  | session expiry 1464594671175 false
2016-05-30T06:19:26.723Z | TRACE  | Arrow Cloud config file: C:\Users\ADMIN\.acs
2016-05-30T06:19:26.725Z | TRACE  | found Arrow Cloud login { mid: '614b7d25d4fea15bd60f62091ceedfb56eda8e6f',
  publishPort: 443,
  publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
  username: 'electronic321@gmail.com',
  cookie: [ 'connect.sid=s%3AXj8EhIXRjnTaC9UnEOUrAz6F.SwVoCz55LSN4vYQ%2Fog533Cv5KixIWgw5JHK6cEeMens; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 06 Jun 2016 07:51:17 GMT; HttpOnly' ],
  defaultEP: 
   { publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
     publishPort: 443 } } , checking nodeACSEndpoint= https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com
2016-05-30T06:19:26.727Z | TRACE  | Arrow Cloud cookie expiry [ 1465199477000 ]
2016-05-30T06:19:26.727Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
2016-05-30T06:19:26.729Z | TRACE  | getCredentials() session:
{
  "ipaddress": "192.168.100.13",
  "username": "electronic321@gmail.com",
  "password": "<OMITTED>",
  "session": "<OMITTED>",
  "nonce": "<OMITTED>",
  "environment": {
    "name": "production",
    "isProduction": true,
    "acsBaseUrl": "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "acsAuthBaseUrl": "https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "nodeACSEndpoint": "https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com"
  },
  "token": "<OMITTED>",
  "fingerprint": "614b7d25d4fea15bd60f62091ceedfb56eda8e6f",
  "fingerprint_description": "Windows Machine ID: 51c8ede0-459f-428a-a13d-18a42f4ce1d5",
  "org_id": 100113556,
  "expiry": 1464594671175
}
2016-05-30T06:19:26.730Z | TRACE  | loading plugins for command "run"
2016-05-30T06:19:26.788Z | TRACE  | run search paths:
[
  "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\.appcelerator\\install\\5.2.2\\package",
  "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\.appcelerator\\install\\5.2.2\\package\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\node_modules",
  "C:\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\.appcelerator\\.npm\\lib\\node_modules"
]
2016-05-30T06:19:26.789Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\appc.js
2016-05-30T06:19:26.911Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 120ms C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\appc.js
2016-05-30T06:19:26.911Z | DEBUG  | run plugin: C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium
2016-05-30T06:19:26.913Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 1ms C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\arrow\appc.js
2016-05-30T06:19:26.917Z | DEBUG  | run plugin: C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\arrow
2016-05-30T06:19:26.922Z | TRACE  | plugin "arrow" failed its "when" function check, skipping...
2016-05-30T06:19:26.923Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via function
2016-05-30T06:19:26.924Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via array
2016-05-30T06:19:26.927Z | TRACE  | executing command "run" with the following plugins:
["titanium"]
2016-05-30T06:19:26.930Z | TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
2016-05-30T06:19:26.933Z | TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
2016-05-30T06:19:28.336Z | TRACE  | session expiry 1464594671175 false
2016-05-30T06:19:28.337Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
2016-05-30T06:19:28.339Z | DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked: 1464583283819
5/30/2016, 11:19:36 AM
Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  Version                     = 10.0.10586
  Architecture                = 32bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 17070088192
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 0.12.10
  npm Version                 = 2.14.9
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.6
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.2.2.GA
  SDK Path                    = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.2.2.GA
  Target Platform             = android
Command
  C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\titanium\lib\titanium.js build run --platform android --log-level trace --sdk 5.2.2.GA --project-dir C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\Thriggle --target device --android-sdk C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk --device-id AVY9KA9631828821 --liveview --deploy-type development --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt --prompt-type socket-bundle --prompt-port 3723 --config-file C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\build-1464589168337.json --no-banner --project-dir C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\Thriggle
[ERROR] :  GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
[ERROR] :  NativeCrypto: ssl=0xeec40600 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0xdddff3c0 arg=0x0
[ERROR] :  NativeCrypto: ssl=0xeec40600 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [3864,9999] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,9999] - In app.js:567,13
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,9999] - Message: Uncaught Error: [LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 192.168.100.13:8324
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: [LiveView] Please ensure your device and computer are on the same network and the port is not blocked.
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,9999] - Source:       throw new Error('[LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at app.js:567: Uncaught Error: [LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 192.168.100.13:8324
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: [LiveView] Please ensure your device and computer are on the same network and the port is not blocked.
```

On the other hand, if I create a new Classic project, it runs fine with LiveView.

Previously, I had Genymotion on my laptop (Window OS), and with that Liveview was not working at all because of different IP addresses on emulator and laptop. That makes sense (I guess). I have uninstalled Genymotion and now I have encountered another problem. My network address is also 192.168.100.1. I have checked it with using Java 32 and 64 bit as well but the same problem persist.

I have spent almost 2 weeks but couldn't figure it out. I am relatively new with Appcelerator and node js, can some one please guide me through this.

**Edited:**

```
    Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.2.2
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
2016-06-01T09:39:39.739Z | TRACE  | set environment to {"registry":"https://software.appcelerator.com","security":"https://security.appcelerator.com","baseurl":"https://platform.appcelerator.com"}
2016-06-01T09:39:39.741Z | TRACE  | checking credentials for existing session
2016-06-01T09:39:40.038Z | TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
2016-06-01T09:39:40.044Z | TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
2016-06-01T09:39:41.812Z | TRACE  | session expiry 1465199772201 false
2016-06-01T09:39:41.818Z | TRACE  | Arrow Cloud config file: C:\Users\ADMIN\.acs
2016-06-01T09:39:41.819Z | TRACE  | found Arrow Cloud login { mid: '614b7d25d4fea15bd60f62091ceedfb56eda8e6f',
  publishPort: 443,
  publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
  username: 'electronic321@gmail.com',
  cookie: [ 'connect.sid=s%3A47blMNQoUpjUFG076uF%2BpTlm.vcgLNB32OzNUsTt4SaysHhBMmGRPNl2ffpm75hHvWec; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 13 Jun 2016 07:56:20 GMT; HttpOnly' ],
  defaultEP: 
   { publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
     publishPort: 443 } } , checking nodeACSEndpoint= https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com
2016-06-01T09:39:41.819Z | TRACE  | Arrow Cloud cookie expiry [ 1465804580000 ]
2016-06-01T09:39:41.819Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
2016-06-01T09:39:41.819Z | TRACE  | getCredentials() session:
{
  "ipaddress": "192.168.100.13",
  "username": "electronic321@gmail.com",
  "password": "<OMITTED>",
  "session": "<OMITTED>",
  "nonce": "<OMITTED>",
  "environment": {
    "name": "production",
    "isProduction": true,
    "acsBaseUrl": "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "acsAuthBaseUrl": "https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "nodeACSEndpoint": "https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com"
  },
  "token": "<OMITTED>",
  "fingerprint": "614b7d25d4fea15bd60f62091ceedfb56eda8e6f",
  "fingerprint_description": "Windows Machine ID: 51c8ede0-459f-428a-a13d-18a42f4ce1d5",
  "org_id": 100113556,
  "expiry": 1465199772201
}
2016-06-01T09:39:41.819Z | TRACE  | loading plugins for command "run"
2016-06-01T09:39:41.865Z | TRACE  | run search paths:
[
  "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\.appcelerator\\install\\5.2.2\\package",
  "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\.appcelerator\\install\\5.2.2\\package\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\node_modules",
  "C:\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\.appcelerator\\.npm\\lib\\node_modules"
]
2016-06-01T09:39:41.865Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\appc.js
2016-06-01T09:39:41.996Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 116ms C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\appc.js
2016-06-01T09:39:41.996Z | DEBUG  | run plugin: C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium
2016-06-01T09:39:41.996Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\arrow\appc.js
2016-06-01T09:39:41.996Z | DEBUG  | run plugin: C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\arrow
2016-06-01T09:39:42.012Z | TRACE  | plugin "arrow" failed its "when" function check, skipping...
2016-06-01T09:39:42.012Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via function
2016-06-01T09:39:42.012Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via array
2016-06-01T09:39:42.012Z | TRACE  | executing command "run" with the following plugins:
["titanium"]
2016-06-01T09:39:42.012Z | TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
2016-06-01T09:39:42.012Z | TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
2016-06-01T09:39:43.734Z | TRACE  | session expiry 1465199772201 false
2016-06-01T09:39:43.742Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
2016-06-01T09:39:43.743Z | DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked: 1464756295656
6/1/2016, 2:39:50 PM
Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  Version                     = 10.0.10586
  Architecture                = 32bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 17070088192
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 0.12.14
  npm Version                 = 2.15.1
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.6
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.2.2.GA
  SDK Path                    = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.2.2.GA
  Target Platform             = android
Command
  C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ADMIN\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\titanium\lib\titanium.js build run --platform android --log-level trace --sdk 5.2.2.GA --project-dir C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\Thriggle --target device --android-sdk C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk --device-id AVY9KA9631828821 --liveview --deploy-type development --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt --prompt-type socket-bundle --prompt-port 4890 --config-file C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\build-1464773983743.json --no-banner --project-dir C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\Thriggle

[INFO] :   Writing build manifest: C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\Thriggle\build\android\build-manifest.json
[INFO] :   Making sure the adb server is running
[INFO] :   Installing apk: C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\Thriggle\build\android\bin\Thriggle.apk
[INFO] :   Installing app on device: HUAWEI TIT-AL00
[LiveView] version 1.0.8
[LiveView] File Server Started on Port 8324
[LiveView] Alloy project monitor started
[LiveView] Event Server Started on Port 8323
[INFO] :   App successfully installed
[INFO] :   Starting app: com.qi.Thriggle/.ThriggleActivity
[DEBUG] :  Trying to start the app...
[INFO] :   Application pid: 4456
-- Start application log -----------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] :  OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:13(114:155); file:external/openssl/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:145;Function:ASN1_get_object
[INFO] :   Project built successfully in 56s 440ms
[WARN] :   V8Object: (KrollRuntimeThread) [165,367] Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
[DEBUG] :  D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=192.168.100.13; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
[DEBUG] :  D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
[DEBUG] :  D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=192.168.100.13; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
[DEBUG] :  D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
[DEBUG] :  D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=192.168.100.13; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
[DEBUG] :  D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
[DEBUG] :  Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.qi.Thriggle :8324
[LiveView] { [Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\Thriggle\i18n\alloy_generated\strings.xml']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Documents\\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\\Thriggle\\i18n\\alloy_generated\\strings.xml' }
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [10292,10292] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,10292] - In app.js:567,13
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,10292] - Message: Uncaught Error: [LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 192.168.100.13:8324
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: [LiveView] Please ensure your device and computer are on the same network and the port is not blocked.
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,10292] - Source:       throw new Error('[LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at app.js:567: Uncaught Error: [LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 192.168.100.13:8324
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: [LiveView] Please ensure your device and computer are on the same network and the port is not blocked.
[ERROR] :  GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
```

This is the relative detail which might be useful.

Comment: Are you running on the actual android device?

Comment: I see you'e using a very old Node.js version. Could you try again with the latest `0.12.x` or `4.x`?

Comment: @developer82 ... yes I am running it on the actual (multiple) devices ...

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator I have tried it on the latest node js version but still the same result ...

Comment: These are the configurations right now 

Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  Version                     = 10.0.10586
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 17070088192
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.4.5
  npm Version                 = 2.15.5
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.6
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.2.2.GA
  SDK Path                    = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.2.2.GA
  Target Platform             = android

Comment: Are you confident `192.168.100.13:8324` is not blocked and accessible from the device? Does LiveView work on Simulator/Emulator?

Comment: When i build a classic project, liveview works fine with it. And if i check the ip address of my device and laptop, they are both on the same network.

Comment: Previously, I have installed Genymotion and tried to run Liveview on emulator but that doesn't work even for the classic project. So i uninstalled the Genymotion and testing on the real devices.

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator can you suggest or recommend me the configuration details (CLI verison, node verison, java etc) which I should laydown in my machine.

Comment: @Umair please see our current Titanium Compatibility Matrix at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator ... I checked that compatibility matrix  and that is okay ... Even i reverted back to windows 8.1 and still encountering the same problem !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out !
In my studio, i was not able to update it .... 
So what we need to do is to install the latest version Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.5.0.201602170821 (currently) and the liveview works like a charm :D

Comment: What was the problem you're facing while updating studio? Any errors?

Comment: @KondalKolipaka while trying to update studio, it always stop the updating process at eclipse.equinox.****  updates ....